# Text within span pushing buttons to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a navbar with a logo to left and some buttons in the middle, but i have some trouble putting the logo. The span with the text is attaching right next to my buttons and if i take it out of my `nav` the logo is too far to the right and pushing my buttons to the left. This is the CSS:

```css
:root {
  --nav-button-color: #ffc300;
  --nav-button-transparent: #ffc40093;
  --font-color-unselected: #737373;
  --font-color-selected: #fff;
  --roboto: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --poppins: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  --font-bold-600: 600;
  --font-bold-700: 700;
  --font-bold-800: 800;
  --font-bold-900: 900;
}

* {
  font-family: var(--roboto);
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-nav {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  color: var(--font-color-unselected);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: var(--font-bold-600);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-nav-selected {
  color: var(--font-color-selected);
  background-color: var(--nav-button-color);
}

.logo {
  font-family: var(--poppins);
  color: var(--font-color-unselected);
  font-weight: var(--font-bold-800);
  font-size: 30px;
}


/*=============================*/

.btn-nav:hover {
  color: var(--font-color-selected);
  background-color: var(--nav-button-transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <span class="logo">Logo</span>
    <button class="btn btn-nav btn-nav-selected">Home</button>
    <button class="btn btn-nav">Shop</button>
    <button class="btn btn-nav">What We Do?</button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with css grid:

```css
:root {
  --nav-button-color: #ffc300;
  --nav-button-transparent: #ffc40093;
  --font-color-unselected: #737373;
  --font-color-selected: #fff;

  --roboto: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --poppins: "Poppins", sans-serif;

  --font-bold-600: 600;
  --font-bold-700: 700;
  --font-bold-800: 800;
  --font-bold-900: 900;
}

* {
  font-family: var(--roboto);
}

.navigation {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-nav {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  color: var(--font-color-unselected);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: var(--font-bold-600);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-nav-selected {
  color: var(--font-color-selected);
  background-color: var(--nav-button-color);
}

.logo {
  font-family: var(--poppins);
  color: var(--font-color-unselected);
  font-weight: var(--font-bold-800);
  font-size: 30px;
  justify-self: flex-start;
}

/*=============================*/

.btn-nav:hover {
  color: var(--font-color-selected);
  background-color: var(--nav-button-transparent);
}
```

```html
<>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <span class="logo">Logo</span>
      <div class="menu">
      <button class="btn btn-nav btn-nav-selected">Home</button>
      <button class="btn btn-nav">Shop</button>
      <button class="btn btn-nav">What We Do?</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</>
```

Comment: There's no need to convert a flexbox layout to grid for this.

Comment: Sure mate, you are 100% right :)  You can show @Meriegg how to do it with flex. I just like grid :) cheers